# service getting killed when screen turns off

Tags: android, service, gps

I have a service that gets GPS coordinates. The problem is it gets killed when the screen turns off. How can make the service to work even if the screen is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your service with `Context.bindService()`, its lifecycle (including when it will be stopped) is bound to the particular calling context (likely to be your Activity). When your Activity shuts down, so will your service. This is what you are experiencing when you turn off your screen.

Use `Context.startService()` if you wish for its lifecycle to be independent of the Activity - this will make sure it will stay alive even if you turn off the screen. You can call Context.stopService() when you want to stop the service.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: I a using                                                     startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this,MyService.class));